# Setting up a python virtual environment with Salt's virtualenv.managed or pip.installed?

Tags: python, virtualenv, salt-stack

I'm trying to use either a `pip.installed` or a `virtualenv.managed` state to set up a virtualenv using a requirements file that lives on the minion (installed by an earlier `git.latest` state). Here's the version using `pip.installed`:

```
mysite-env:
  virtualenv.managed:
    - name: /opt/django/mysite
    - cwd: /opt/django/mysite
    - user: mysite
    - runas: mysite
    - system_site_packages: True

mysite-reqs:
  pip.installed:
    - no_index: True
    - find_links: http://pypi.mysite.com/
    - requirements: /opt/django/mysite/requirements/production.txt
    - pip_exists_action: switch
    - cwd: /opt/django/mysite
    - pip_bin: /opt/django/mysite/bin/pip
    - bin_env: /opt/django/mysite
    - user: mysite
    - watch:
      - git: mysite-project
```

When I try and run this state, I get this error:

```
          ID: mysite-reqs
    Function: pip.installed
      Result: False
     Comment: Unable to process requirements file /opt/django/mysite/requirements/production.txt. Error: Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
              Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/requirements.txt'
              Storing debug log for failure in /home/mysite/.pip/pip.log
```

But that's not the path I'm passing to requirements. This looks kind of like a bug, like maybe `/tmp/requirements.txt` is hard-coded, because it expects me to use a `salt://` URL instead of a local file path.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug, and is there a good way to work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's my first day using Saltstack and Python and I was googling for environment configuration help and came across your question in my search results.

The next [search result](http://www.frankwiles.com/blog/2013/nov/04/saltstack-and-multiple-pip-requirements-files/) I clicked contains the same error as yours and suggests that this is caused by SaltStack moving the environment to /tmp for chowning.

The solution was to add the following to your salt state:

```
no_chown: True
```

Hope it helps.